# Area of x^2 + y with {x, y} ∈ ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 < 2, {x, y}]

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, regions

I want to get the area of the set $\{x^2 + y\, | \,x^2 + y^2 < 2\}$, meaning I want to get the area of the surface defined by

$\qquad f(x,y) = x^2 + y$

with the domain given by $x^2 + y^2 < 2$.

I tried using `ImplicitRegion`, and I can even plot it with

```
Plot3D[x^2 + y, {x, y} ∈ ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 < 2, {x, y}]]
```

but I don't know how to measure the area of the surface.

Comment: It is unclear what you're asking.  What does it mean the "area" of $x^2 + y$?  And why is your domain $x^2 + y^2 < 2$ but your Plot3D have an ImplicitRegion $x^2 + y^2 < 9$?  Please fix your question!

Comment: The Plot3D also plots a different function (2x+y) instead of (x^2+y).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe the question is about the area of a surface. If that's the case, the answer is as follows:

```
surface = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y == z && x^2 + y^2 < 2, {x, y, z}]
```

This is a 2D region embedded in 3D space:

```
RegionDimension[surface]
RegionEmbeddingDimension[surface]
(*2*)
(*3*)
```

The area is found by using `RegionMeasure`:

```
RegionMeasure[surface]
N[%, 10]
(*2/3 Sqrt[2] (3 EllipticE[-4] + 5 EllipticK[-4])*)
(*12.21203137*)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

```
Integrate[x*x + y, {x, y} ∈ Disk[{0, 0}, Sqrt [2]]]
```

which returns $\pi$.

However, if it is school work, the "manual" way to do that is a change of variable like this one: $(x,y)=(r\cos \theta,r\sin \theta)$

After Jacobian calculation you get:

```
Integrate[r*(r*r*Cos[θ]^2 + r*Sin[θ]), {r, 0, Sqrt[2]}, {θ, 0, 2 π}]
```

Which (fortunately) also gives $\pi$

---

**Update:** Now if you want area of the surface, you can use this formula: 
$$
\int_\Omega \| \left( \begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 0 \\ \partial_x f \end{array} \right)\times \left( \begin{array}{c} 0 \\ 1 \\ \partial_y f \end{array} \right) \| dxdy
$$
with $\Omega$ your centered disk of radius $\sqrt{2}$ and $f:(x,y)\rightarrow x^2+y$. You get, after change of variable
$$
\int_0^\sqrt{2}\int_0^{2\pi} r \sqrt{4 r^2 \cos ^2(\theta )+2}\ drd\theta
$$
which unfortunately involves Elliptic functions...

Under Mathematica:

```
f[x_, y_] := x*x + y

vx = D[{x, y, f[x, y]}, x];
vy = D[{x, y, f[x, y]}, y];

dareaCartesian = 
 Simplify[Norm[Cross[vx, vy], 2], Assumptions -> {x ∈ Reals}]

dareaPolar = 
 r*Simplify[dareaCartesian /. x -> r*Cos[θ] /. y -> r*Sin[θ] ]

area = Integrate[dareaPolar, {r, 0, Sqrt[2]}, {θ, 0, 2*Pi}] 

N[area]
```

which prints:
$$
\sqrt{4 x^2+2}
$$
$$
r \sqrt{4 r^2 \cos ^2(\theta )+2}
$$
$$
\frac{2}{3} \sqrt{2} (5  EllipticK(-4)+3  EllipticE(-4))
$$
$$
12.212
$$

Answer (score 2):

```
    Integrate[(x^2 + y) Boole[x^2 + y^2 < 2], {x, -Infinity, 
   Infinity}, {y, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

Pi

(* If you want a plot, do this: *)

```
 Plot3D[(x^2 + y) Boole[x^2 + y^2 < 2], {x, -Sqrt[2], 
  Sqrt[2]}, {y, -Sqrt[2], Sqrt[2]}, 
 RegionFunction -> (#1^2 + #2^2 < 2 &), Filling -> Axis, 
 FillingStyle -> Directive[Gray, Opacity[0.2]]]
```